# Intellisense Not Recognizing Python Module(Pygame)

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, pygame

I was using Visual Studio 2013 to edit some python code, and Intellisense is giving me a green squiggly line when I  `import pygame`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using Eclipse with Pygame. It doesn't recognize it.
Visual-Studio2013 just probably thinks something is wrong.
The code should still run fine.